# Why i can't send kendo grid filters from javascript ajax request to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo mvc grid and i want to export it to csv file on my button click on toolbar.
When i click button i can get grid options and total count of data but cannot express filters to controller.

Do you have any sugession?
Here is my js code

```
var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

$.ajax({
    url: "../Controller/DataExport",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'request': dataSource.transport.parameterMap({ sort: dataSource.sort(), filter: dataSource.filter(), group: dataSource.group() }), 'count': dataSource.total() }),
    success: function (data) {
        //do smth..
    }
});

 public async Task<ActionResult> GetDataExport([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string count){
        // try to get request.Filter but it's always null....
  }
```